# How do I delete my account from this stack exchange site?

Tags: support, status-completed

I want to continue to use my account on other stack exchange sites, but want to delete it from this one.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found the answer [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).